# Hibernate: how can I call a column create with @Formula annotation

Tags: hibernate, formula

I want to execute a LEFT_JOIN between two columns:

- 'codiceSpedizione' that is a column of 'ProvaInd' table
- 'idCod' that is a concatenation of two columns of 'ProvaRiep' table (so, idCod isn't an existing column)

I execute the concatenation with @Formula annotation inside dataobject (java class that mapped the database):

@Formula("concat(id,substr(codiceSpedizione,6))")

private String idCod;

Now I want to call idCod in Dbozzo.java:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="codice", referencedColumnName="idCod", nullable=false)
public Dbotivo getDbotivo() {
    return dbotivo;
}
```

But if I call 'idCod' in referencedColumnName, I get this error:

org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on     dataobject.Requezzo.Dbozzo references an unknown entity: dataobject.Dbozzo

Can someone explain me this error?
I'm not sure..the Formula annotation create a virtual column? Otherwise, 'idCod' is a virtual column?

Thank you for attention and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure, but I think you could use @JoinColumnOrFormula

See "*5.1.7.1. Using a foreign key or an association table*" on the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html

> You can use a SQL fragment to simulate a physical join column using
>   the @JoinColumnOrFormula / @JoinColumnOrformulas annotations (just
>   like you can use a SQL fragment to simulate a property column via the
>   @Formula annotation).

```
@Entity
public class Ticket implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula="(firstname + ' ' + lastname)")
    public Person getOwner() {
        return person;
    }
    ...
}
```